# React Native Share Method Multiple Windows

Tags: react-native

I’m using react native share, to share text content. The issue is multiple windows are opened over each other on clicking share button multiple times. Even I have disabled button on share click but it is of no use as well.

The standard way is if share window is already open, on clicking the share button again the window get closed. How can it be done?

```
<Button 
 transparent
 disabled={this.state.isShareDisabled}
  onPress={() => this.onShare()}>

onShare() {
    if(!this.state.isShareDisabled)
    {
    this.setState(
        {
            isShareDisabled:true
        }
    )
    Share.share({
      message: “Message test”,
      url: ”www.google.com”,
      title: “Title test”
    }, {
      // Android only:
      dialogTitle: 'Share',
      // iOS only:
      excludedActivityTypes: [
        'com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToTwitter'
      ]
    }) .then((result) => {
        this.setState(
            {
                isShareDisabled: false,
            }
        )
    })
}
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dismissed action. Share event support it on both android and iOS.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it by doing the following, just required to check dismissedAction.

```
onShare() {
    if(!this.state.isShareDisabled)
    {
    this.setState(
        {
            isShareDisabled:true
        }
    )

    Share.share({ message:  'test',
         url: 'test url',
         title: 'test title'
         },
{
   // Android only:
   dialogTitle: 'Share',
   // iOS only:
   excludedActivityTypes: [
     'com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToTwitter'
   ]
}).then(({action, activityType}) => {
  if(action === Share.dismissedAction) {
    this.setState(
        {
            isShareDisabled: false,
        }
    )
    }
  else {
    this.setState(
        {
         isShareDisabled: false,
        }
    )
  }
});
}
  }
```

Comment: Another way could have been cleaning up on componenWillUnmount or setup everything on componentWillMount or the constructor.